# Run a script on another machine accessible through another machine over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, script

I would like to run a script located on my development machine on machine B that is only accessible via machine A.

So, my development machine --(SSH)--> machineA --(SSH)--> machineB

How do I do that? The script also takes arguments.

Comment: Hi hebbo. I hope my close vote didn't make you delete the other question, that was not my intention. I marked this as a duplicate since this is basically a subset of the original question (how to run commands via a jump host), but I was in the process of writing an answer for it since there was an interesting [quote](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)-related issue in there as well. I'll just leave this link here in case you want to keep the question deleted but still want to learn about quoting.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [**tunnel** via a **jump host** or **proxy**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Passing_Through_One_or_More_Gateways_Using_ProxyJump). There are several ways of doing this based on what exactly you are trying to do, but I believe putting something like this in ~/.ssh/config locally should work for your case:

```
Host b
        ProxyJump a
```

Tested with this configuration:

```
Host localhost
    ProxyJump 127.0.0.1
```

And it works like this (trimmed to show just the hops):

```
$ ssh -v localhost 'ls ~'
Authenticated to 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:22).
Authenticated to localhost (via proxy).
[ls output]
```

Comment: I think that would probably work if you explain your answer a bit more. I am not very familiar with sshd config...so I do not know where each one of these configs go.

Comment: Is this clearer?

Comment: Is this clearer?

Answer (score -1):

Let's say, you have the below script in the remote dev-machine.

```
remote-machine-x$ cat /home/userA/dev/zeebash
#!/bin/bash

 echo "$@" | mail -s subject mygmailaccount@gmail.com
```

To execute this script from local machine, given that you have already set-up ssh-key, you can do it with something like this:

```
p="hi man" ; ssh userA@remote-machine-x  "/home/userA/dev/zeebash   "$p" "
```

Comment: I do not think you understood the question.

Comment: The question is "Run a script on another machine accessible through another machine over ssh". If you mean something else, please explain.

Comment: @zee OP is talking about three machines - local, A (the proxy host) and B (the server). They want to SSH *via* A to B and then run a script on B in one command. My solution does that.